# Deploy an azure cloud service automatically - not within Visual Studio/VSTS -

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have created in my VS2015 an azure cloud service with a worker role. These are 2 projects.

I want to know how can I pack and then publish this cloud service with a tool/cli?

When I google for 'deploy azure cloud service' I get only result saying to do it within Visual Studio or Visual Studio Team System.

This is NOT what I want!

Comment: Almost everything in azure has a powershell commandlet to do the configuration from the command line.  I don't know specifically about cloud services, but it would surprise me if that wasn't in there.

Comment: Did you tried googling "deploy azure cloud service powershell" ?

Comment: Of course I checked my powershell ISE, searched in the modules/cmdlets for 'cloud' and got 4 not interesting results.

Comment: When I read this: https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2014/02/06/deploying-cloud-services-to-azure-with-powershell/ - I can just shake my head... seems someone did the job for Microsoft...

Comment: Have you installed the Azure SDK?  Powershell doesn't contain stuff for azure by default.

Comment: I have installed the latest azure sdk with appr. 400MB in size. And Regarding to Fred Han`s answer you should be surprised now, because cspack could not be found in the powershell commandlets :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the [cspack command line tool to package a cloud service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-model-and-package#servicepackagecspkg). If the application only contains worker role, you could refer to the following command.

```
cspack D:\xxx\xxx\ServiceDefinition.csdef /role:WorkerRole1;D:\xxx\WorkerRole1\bin;D:\xxx\WorkerRole1\bin\Debug\WorkerRole1.dll
```

And you could refer to the *PublishCloudService.ps1* script template in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-continuous-delivery#5-publish-a-package-using-tfs-team-build).

> cspack could not be found in the powershell commandlets

The cspack could run in Windows PowerShell on my side. I add `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\[sdk-version]\bin`  in Path system environment variables, and I could run the following command to package a cloud service.

[image]

Comment: Is there a better way to do this in 2019 ?